# To fire an event when Server is hit or when Session IDs are refreshed in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

Basically i want to implement Session Management in my application having a Session Timeout of 1 hour.That is i want to show a pop-up 15 minues before Session timeout.

In my .NET application there is a home page and from that home page other child pages are getting opened by clicking on different links present on the Home page.Now The session Timeout warning pop-up can be displayed by implementing a timer by writing a cient side script code and using the javascipt method- setinterval on the home page.

But the problem arises when the user goes to any child page/window from the Home page and refreshes the session ids by hitting the server by fetching data from database from that child page. But the session timeout warning timer implmented on the home page displays the warning pop-up even if the Session has been refreshed by activities done on the child page. As i cannot implement timer on every cild pages because it is a vast application having numerous child and nested chld pages, so what i want to ask is that- **can we fire an event on the home page** to reset the session timeout timer **whenever the server is hit** ?

If we can do it , then my job is done

Comment: This actually is not a question, is something that you need to decide and design.

Comment: More importantly, any request to the server would automatically increase the timeout period meaning that client side would be the only solution.

Comment: @Aristos: my bad Sir, I have edited the last sentence to finally make it a question.

Comment: @Gavin: That's why only i want fire an event on the client side to reset the session timeout timer whenever a request to the server is sent.

Comment: @ShivamGupta Do you understand how Session's work? The session is kept alive for every request that user makes. The only reason the client would need to know that the session is about to timeout, is when the client will not make any requests within the timeout period. In which case, you simply set a timer on the page for the timeout period which will fire 15 minutes before the session expires. If you make any ajax requests, you can simply call `clearTimeout` and reset it to start counting again.

Comment: @Gavin: I completely agree with you . I can do what you are saying if the user stays on a single page . But the problem arises when the user opens a child window from the Home page(on which session timeout functionality is implemented) and requests the server from that child page , then how can we call the clearTimeout method that is implemented on the Home page and not on the child page, where the user currently is working, and moreover the timer implemented on the home page is also running.

Comment: @ShivamGupta, how are you opening the new window? Via `target="_blank"` or `window.open`? Either way, you can simply call `clearTimeout` before you open the new window.

Comment: @Gavin: window.open and ShowModalDialog(url) And from that child page several other nested child pages are being called but the clearTimeout is implemented on the Client side script of HOME page.

Comment: @ShivamGupta, before you call either, simply call clearTimeout on the parent page. failing that, use `window.opener` to reference back to the parent window and call a custom function that clears it for you once the new window opens.

Comment: @Gavin. THANKS for your suggestion . Yes it can be done but in my application thee are 100-200 child pages being called So it would require code change at all those 100 places. Moreover there are even scenarios where 5 nested child pages are called from 1st child page ( thus to reach back  to the home page, 6 child pages need to be closed first)

Comment: @ShivamGupta in which case, you will need to handle it on the parent page before you open any other windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot receive notice of a session clear or if session is getting close to posting back from the server.  You can achieve what you want to do from the client, but you need to handle the ajax postback scenario.  By listening to Sys.Application events, you can find out when the AJAX request has ended, and restart the timer (should be the endRequest event).  Postbacks to the server should naturally refresh the timer as your session is sliding expiration, and a postback would reset the timer anyway.

This is how I did it in a past project.